# Exporting org-mode to Markdown does not render the title?

Tags: org-mode, html, markdown, markdown-mode

I have the following in org-mode:

```
#+TITLE: My title                                                                                                                                      
#+SUBTITLE: My subtitle
```

Both show up just fine when exporting to HTML but are nowhere to be seen when exporting to Markdown. Why is that and how to fix it?

PS: I'm using Emacs version 27.1.

Comment: Yes - `ox-html` preserves these as metadata using the function `org-html--build-meta-info`; `ox-md` does nothing similar. I don't know much about Markdown, but you might send a bug report with `M-x org-submit-bug-report` and see what the maintainers have to say about it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097894/markdown-tag-for-document-title seems to indicate that there is no title markup in Markdown :-) Of course, you can find another dialect (or invent your own - everybody seems to have done it...) - but there might not be an official way to specify a title. Let me repeat however: I don't know very much about Markdown.

Answer (score 1):

Using the info provided by NickD, and inspecting `org-html--build-meta-info` it becomes quite straightforward to include 'some kind of title' in the md export.

You could advise `org-md-template` as follows to export the title:

```lisp
(defun org-md-export-title-advice (orig-fun &rest args)
  (let* ((res (apply orig-fun args))
         (title (org-element-interpret-data (plist-get (nth 1 args) :title))))
    (concat "# " title "\n"
            res)))

(advice-add 'org-md-template :around #'org-md-export-title-advice)
```

Of course, here I am simply formatting the title as a level-1 heading. However, you could use any of the tricks from that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097894/markdown-tag-for-document-title) in NickD's comment (e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60180113/6837095)) to modify the formatting (just change the args in the `concat` form).

Alternatively, you could also just redefine the `org-md-template` function directly.